# 2D puppet animation in Unity3d 4.6 doesn't work, only parent object moves

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 2d, unity3d-2dtools

I have a problem with a 2d puppet animation in Unity.
I followed the instructions in this thread:
[2d puppet rigging thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/2d-puppet-rigging-tips-tricks.245564/)

I made a crouching animation, if I click the play button of the animation, it looks good.
But I made it to the default animation in the animator and when I start the game I only see the movement of the highest parent element. The movement of the child elements (the legs) doesn't work.
I don't understand why :(
Restarting Unity doesn't fixed it.
[image: 2dpuppet animation]

I asked the same question at Unity Answers, but my question has not been unlocked by the mods.
Another question I asked later was unlocked.... I don't understand which criteria works there.

Comment: the author of that thread (zombiegorilla) is active on the unity forums, you might want to try a reply to the thread you're following or a pm for a more direct response?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea, i will do this :)